# Using boost bind to access member function of inner class

Tags: c++, boost, bind

I'm trying to access a *member function* of a *nested class* in a find_if expression.

My code below causes a compile error in the bind expression - (‘COuter::innerClass’ is not a class or namespace).

**Could you help me with the correct bind expression?**

```
vector<COuter> vec;

vec.push_back(COuter());

vector<COuter>::const_iterator it = 
  find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), bind(&COuter::innerClass::GetTemp, _1) == 42);
```

My example classes:

---

```
class CInner
{
public:
    CInner() : _temp(42) {};

    int GetTemp() const
    {
        return _temp;
    }

private:

    int _temp;
};

class COuter
{
public:
    CInner innerClass;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct expression is `bind(&CInner::GetTemp, bind(&COuter::innerClass, _1))`.

Comment: What is this extra bind doing there? You should just pass in a reference to the member.

Comment: @CashCow: you need an extra bind to traverse through the extra object innerClass. It works as it should with gcc-4.4.

Comment: @CashCow, the desired ordinary-C++ expression is this: `vec[i].innerClass.GetTemp() == 42`. The `_1` variable will refer to `vec[i]`, so the inner `bind` expression gives us a reference to `vec[i].innerClass`. The outer `bind` gets us its `GetTemp` member.